# How many grams of CO2 are emitted to produce one paper napkin?

Tags: paper, greenhouse-gas-emissions, energy-use

Does using paper napkins have a high carbon impact?

Answer (score 2):

I found a few different references for this:

- 10 g CO<sub>2</sub>e per paper towel (from [the Guardian, 2010](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/green-living-blog/2010/aug/05/carbon-footprint-drying-hands))
- 10 g CO<sub>2</sub> per paper napkin (from [Treehugger, 2009](https://www.treehugger.com/clean-technology/are-paper-napkins-more-environmentally-friendly.html))
- 7.3 g CO<sub>2</sub>e per virgin paper towel (from [MIT/Dyson study, 2011](http://environmental-management.ca/lca/LCA_MIT_Hand-Dryers_2011.pdf))
- 7.4 g CO<sub>2</sub>e per recycled paper towel (same study)

While several of these studies are looking at hand drying (for which I [wrote an earlier answer](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/5894/3379)), the Treehugger article looked specifically at napkins used during a meal, considering the manufacture as well as washing and drying.

Looking at **linen**, **cotton**, and **paper** napkins, the study found that **paper napkins are best in a restaurant setting** where cotton or linen napkins would likely be washed in hot water with chemicals after each meal.

**For home use, linen napkins are preferable to cotton napkins** (112 g CO<sub>2</sub>e vs 1 kg, respectively, for production), and both are better than paper if washed only when needed. Additionally, washing in cold water with a natural detergent and line drying will further reduce impact.